# PHP rtrim to Remove the Last Space and What Follows

Tags: php, trim, character-trimming

In PHP how to use trim() or rtrim() to remove the last space and the characters after?

Expample:

> Any Address 23B

to become

> Any Address

AND

> Another Address 6

to become

> Another Address

Comment: Since the end is dynamic, it is not possible with trim. Regex (preg_replace) would be the right way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant. Trim is for spaces and tabs etc, or specified characters. What you want is more specific logic.

If you want it from the last space:

```
$lastSpace = strrpos($string, ' ');
$street = substr($string, 0, $lastSpace);
$number = substr($string, $lastSpace+1);
```

You can also `implode` on space, use `array_pop` to get the last value and then `implode`, but array functions on string manipulation are costly compared to a `substr`.
You can also use a regex to get the last values, but while it's better than array manipulation for string, you should use it as a plan B as a regex isn't the most lightweight option either.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a regex?

```php
$address = 'Any Address 23B';
$matches = [];
preg_match('/(?P<street>.*) \w+$/', $address, $matches);

print_r($matches['street']); // OUTPUT: "Any Address"
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you dont wanna use the answers above, here is one solution without regex:

```
$string = 'Any Address 23B';
$stringRev = explode(' ', strrev($string), 2);
echo strrev($stringRev[1]);  //result: Any Address
```